# Aligning a Paragraph to the right in a MigraDoc table cell

Tags: pdfsharp, migradoc

PDFsharp-MigraDoc-gdi v1.50.4845-RC2

I have a heading row at the top of my table.  I can align the paragraph vertically by:

```
topHeaderRow.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
```

I also have a column down the left of the table with row headings in it.  I want to be able to align these to the right.  There does not seem to be an equivalent option?

Does anyone know how to right-align a paragraph in a table cell?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.  Seems on rows, it is done a different way:

```
row.Cells[0].Format.Alignment = ParagraphAlignment.Right;
```